# java.io.Console ao depurar no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console

Estou tentando usar a [java.io.Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) de dentro do Eclipse. Porém, sempre que chamo [System.console()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console--) me retorna null.

No jetty, é possível passar parâmetros no console do eclipse. Por exemplo, se eu pressionar 'x' no console do eclipse, o jetty é finalizado.

Alguém sabe como o obter oo considerar a *view* Console do eclipse como um console para o java no modo debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O System.console() não funciona no eclipse porque na verdade, apesar te existir uma view chamada console, ela não é considerada um console de fato. Se você executar o mesmo código via terminal, ele irá funcionar.

Essa questão é discutida aqui:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429

Você pode utilizar isso aqui:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String content = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("O contéudo lido foi: "+content);
scanner.close();
```

A view console do Eclipse é acessada através do System.in e System.out.